# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to use ReactJS with font-awesome but I am getting a module not found error.  The files are in the npm modules folder so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

I have the following in my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "partner-portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

I have run the following commands, and the libraries have been added to my `npm_modules` folder:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@latest
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
```

But when I include it like this:

```
import { faBell } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons"

function Form() {

    return(
        <div className='container w-[1000px] p-5 mx-auto border rounded-2xl'>
            <div className='flex flex-wrap'>
                <label className="mr-5">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-row w-full justify-end'>
                <button className="pointer-events-auto ml-8 rounded-md bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-3 text-[0.8125rem] font-semibold leading-5 text-white hover:bg-indigo-500">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBell} />
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
    webpackMissingModule bundle.js:214
    js bundle.js:214
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 11**
```

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Edit:

I've moved on now and I'm trying to use ReactRouter, which I've installed using the following command `npm i react-router`.  As you cas see from my updated `package.json` (above) I have react-dom, react-router, react-router-config, react-router-dom in there.  I run `npm install` and get no problems.  However when I try:

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
} from "react-router"
```

I still get the same error.  `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-router'`  Again, the files are there in the node_modules folder.  What am I doing wrong??!

Comment: Could You please add link to the repo ?

Answer (score 13):

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

I had a similar issue and solved it by running the above commands then I stopped the script and did npm start and the error was fixed. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

First install "SVG Core" icons

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
```

or

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
```

Then choice your prefer "icon package" (solid, brand, regular)

**NPM:**

```
# Free icons styles
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

**YARN**

```
# Free icons styles
yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

If dont doenst another step: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons

If u are using docker. Restart container.

Font: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install,

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Remove all others and use the below code,

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faBell } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBell} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Worked for me !!

Comment: Im still getting the same error.  I ran the commands you suggested above and I'm including and its not working.  The app works fine without it, just can't seem to find the module for some reason.  I'm also using tailwindcss, would that conflict at all?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how to remove others as you suggested.

Comment: Delete all `fortawesome` related things from the `package.json`. Then delete `node_modules` folder. And then run `npm install`. Then follow the procedure in my answer. Everything will work fine.

Comment: Delete `    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",` from `package.json`.

Comment: If there is any conflicts with `tailwindcss`. You will get error while installing `fortawesome` modules. Let me know, If you get any error messages.

Comment: Does this answer fixes your issue ?

Comment: Sorry, No.  I did exactly as you described, no error messages.  Does it affect things because I'm running in side a docker container?

Comment: No it wont happen. Are you getting the same error ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a private repo for work :(

Comment: Okay no probs. Can you share your `package.json` file alone ?

Comment: I've updated the question and put the most recent package.json in there (the top code segment).  I've moved on to try and use ReactRouter, but I am getting the same error with that too (Cannot find module 'react-router') So obviously I have some fundemental problem with the way my modules are loaded.

Comment: It is `react-router-dom` and not `react-router`. It is `npm install react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I had followed the steps on the site but kept getting errors.

The problem for me was that I installed the fontawesome dependencies in another terminal while my build was running as well so I didn't get any feedback.

On restarting the build after the errors, I finally got the feedback that the version of the dependency I installed was to recent for the version of react native I was using, I was also given a line of code to run to get the right version

Answer (score 0):

For me, this solution worked.

1. Delete @fortawesom folder inside node_modules
2. Install again by npm i if they are already in package.json

Answer (score 0):

first install react icons

```
npm install react-icons --save
```

then test your icon

```
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';
class Question extends React.Component {
 render() {
return <h3> Lets go for a <FaBeer />? </h3>
}
}
```

for more icons go to

```
https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't konw why, but it's ok. I changed the default port 3000 to 3020 and the result was fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).